# iOS random crash because of memory corruption

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

My app has many random crashes recently. Fabric shows the crash rate is about 1%. The crash session number and the crash user number is very close, which means it's very random.

The crash shows several different callstacks on Fabric, here are three of them.

==========1===============

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  QuartzCore                     0x188715730 CALayerGetSuperlayer + 20
1  UIKit                          0x188dd6fa0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) superview] + 44
2  UIKit                          0x188dd7a88 -[UIView nextResponder] + 108
3  UIKit                          0x188e9d99c -[UIResponder _containsResponder:] + 56
4  UIKit                          0x188ecfc80 -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 576
5  UIKit                          0x188f13238 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 1536
6  UIKit                          0x188f12aec -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 360
7  UIKit                          0x188fda30c -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 336
8  UIKit                          0x188e11398 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
9  UIKit                          0x188fda160 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 468
10 UIKit                          0x188e11398 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
11 UIKit                          0x188dfa474 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 612
12 UIKit                          0x188fd9d98 -[UITabBar(Static) _buttonUp:] + 128
13 UIKit                          0x188e11398 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
14 UIKit                          0x188dfa474 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 612
15 UIKit                          0x188e10d34 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 592
16 UIKit                          0x188dcff54 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 8536
17 CoreFoundation                 0x18431c2a4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
18 CoreFoundation                 0x184319230 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 360
19 CoreFoundation                 0x184319610 __CFRunLoopRun + 836
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1842452d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
21 GraphicsServices               0x18dc9b6fc GSEventRunModal + 168
22 UIKit                          0x188e42f40 UIApplicationMain + 1488
```

======================2=======================

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  QuartzCore                     0x18e7ca1d0 CALayerGetSuperlayer + 20
1  UIKit                          0x191e4e9d4 -[UIView(UIKitManual) superview] + 128
2  UIKit                          0x1915d3a5c -[UIView nextResponder] + 120
3  UIKit                          0x19197d620 -[UIResponder _canChangeFirstResponder:toResponder:] + 64
4  UIKit                          0x19165c01c -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 224
5  UIKit                          0x19169b118 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didStartTransition:] + 760
6  UIKit                          0x1917758ac -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 3852
7  UIKit                          0x19168f7bc -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 676
8  UIKit                          0x19168f424 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 64
9 UIKit                          0x19168f388 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188
10 UIKit                          0x1915d5cc0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1200
11 QuartzCore                     0x18e7c6274 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
12 QuartzCore                     0x18e7bade8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
13 QuartzCore                     0x18e7baca8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
14 QuartzCore                     0x18e73634c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
15 QuartzCore                     0x18e75d3ac CA::Transaction::commit() + 504
16 QuartzCore                     0x18e75de78 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 120
17 CoreFoundation                 0x18b4549a8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
18 CoreFoundation                 0x18b452630 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
19 CoreFoundation                 0x18b452a7c __CFRunLoopRun + 956
20 CoreFoundation                 0x18b382da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
21 GraphicsServices               0x18cded074 GSEventRunModal + 100
22 UIKit                          0x19163dc9c UIApplicationMain + 208
```

=========3========

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18fe4c1a0 objc_retain + 16
1  UIKit                          0x1974fba5c -[UIView nextResponder] + 120
2  UIKit                          0x1978a45ec -[UIResponder _resignIfContainsFirstResponder] + 156
3  UIKit                          0x1974fb76c -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:] + 568
4  UIKit                          0x197507d88 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 424
5  UIKit                          0x197773000 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2 + 1556
6  UIKit                          0x19750e964 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 104
7  UIKit                          0x1976e0950 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke + 260
8  UIKit                          0x1977fd388 +[UIView(Internal) _performBlockDelayingTriggeringResponderEvents:] + 220
9 UIKit                          0x1976e0450 -[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:] + 1060
10 UIKit                          0x19769d818 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 3704
11 UIKit                          0x1975b77bc -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 676
12 UIKit                          0x1975b7424 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 64
13 UIKit                          0x1975b7388 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188
14 UIKit                          0x1974fdcc0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1200
15 QuartzCore                     0x1946ee274 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
16 QuartzCore                     0x1946e2de8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
17 QuartzCore                     0x1946e2ca8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
18 QuartzCore                     0x19465e34c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
19 QuartzCore                     0x1946853ac CA::Transaction::commit() + 504
20 UIKit                          0x1974f3308 _afterCACommitHandler + 256
21 CoreFoundation                 0x19137c9a8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
22 CoreFoundation                 0x19137a630 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
23 CoreFoundation                 0x19137aa7c __CFRunLoopRun + 956
24 CoreFoundation                 0x1912aada4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
25 GraphicsServices               0x192d15074 GSEventRunModal + 100
26 UIKit                          0x197565c9c UIApplicationMain + 208
```

I have no idea which page or what action caused this crash, and I can't reproduce this either.

Also tried Xcode analytics, zombie, memory instrument, with no luck.

Please let me know if you have any comments.

Comment: check any listing from webservice which is show the images and the image size is large so in older device, it lead to crash.

Comment: No, the crash happens on all systems from iOS 8 to iOS 10

Comment: please send fabric error message

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I am getting the same thing here

Comment: Yeah, I solved this issue finally. It's because of some other code, related with "copy-paste"

Comment: Hi
Do you remember what caused the error?